# Importing user defined modules in Python

Tags: python, module

I have the following module definition for a Stack:

```
class Stack:
 def __init__(self):
     self.items = []

 def isEmpty(self):
     return self.items == []

 def push(self, item):
     self.items.append(item)

 def pop(self):
     return self.items.pop()

 def peek(self):
     return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

 def size(self):
     return len(self.items)
```

I am trying to import this module in another program as follows:

```
import Stack
s=Stack()

print(s.isEmpty())
s.push(4)
s.push('dog')
print(s.peek())
```

I get the following error:

```
s=Stack()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Have I imported incorrectly? The Stack class is within the same folder as the class that is implementing it. Or have I called the constructor incorrectly?

Comment: what is the name of the file where `Stack` is ? and probably you gonna need the `__init__.py` file on the folder. Also have in mind that your class is named stack and not Stack with a capital letter.

Comment: If file with `Stack` named `pizza.py` try `from pizza import Stack`

Comment: You should use: from Stack import Stack. In 's=Stack()', the 'Stack' is a module name.

Comment: File name is Stack.py. Thanks fred.yu. Problem solved!

Comment: The code in the traceback doesn't match the code you claim to be running.

Comment: @fred.yu: you should make an answer of this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
from Stack import Stack
```

In 's=Stack()', the 'Stack' is a module name.